# How to transfer coins from Super Contract back to account

Tags: wallets, addresses

Some funds were mistakenly transferred to an ethereum based smart contract address instead to a personal address.

Is there any way anyone (coin developers maybe) can transfer coins from this smart contract address back to my personal address or are they simply gone forever?

Help much appreciated

Comment: They are probably gone, unless the contract allows a withdrawal.  Can you paste a link to the code of the contract and its address?

Comment: Go to: http://www.xaurum.org/tutorial.html
Scroll down to: A) BASIC CONTRACT: Xaurum ERC20 Proxy
There you will find the address and the json code

Comment: Does it allow a withdrawal?

Comment: [Xaurum.sol](https://github.com/XaurumTeam/XaurumOnEthereum/blob/master/Xaurum.sol) - they might have some control features. Did you contact them yet?

Comment: @5chdn They say they don't have any control over it